# MySQL Select distinct values and select more

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a table with a specified id, value1, value2 and value3

MyTable1 looks like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID   | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 103    | 202    | 3212   |
| 2    | 103    | 202    | 7667   |
| 3    | 103    | 202    | 7567   |
| 4    | 103    | 203    | 6545   |
| 5    | 103    | 203    | 9787   |
| 6    | 106    | 203    | 6545   |
| 7    | 106    | 203    | 6575   |
| 8    | 106    | 202    | 8909   |
| 9    | 106    | 206    | 4656   |
| 10   | 106    | 205    | 5676   |
| 11   | 106    | 208    | 9088   |
| 12   | 107    | 202    | 8998   |
| 13   | 107    | 205    | 5675   |
| 14   | 107    | 204    | 9787   |
| 15   | 107    | 204    | 6454   |
| 16   | 107    | 206    | 9089   |
| 17   | 107    | 202    | 1233   |
| 18   | 107    | 205    | 8765   |
| 19   | 108    | 208    | 8900   |
| 20   | 103    | 205    | 6543   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

And MyTable2 looks like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+---------+
| ID   | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | STATUS  |
+------+--------+--------+---------+
| 1    | 103    | 209    | OK      |
| 2    | 105    | 203    | DEAD    |
| 3    | 107    | 205    | GOOD    |
| 4    | 104    | 202    | WRONG   |
| 5    | 103    | 203    | WOW     |
+------+--------+--------+---------+
```

When I want results. I am using the this code.

> SELECT DISTINCT value1,value2 FROM MyTable1 WHERE value1 = 103

The result looks like this.

```
+--------+---------+
| VALUE1 | VALUE2  |
+--------+---------+
| 103    | 202     |
| 103    | 203     |
| 103    | 205     |
+--------+---------+
```

But I want to add a status column and that comes MyTable2

I tried something like this, but I did not get the result.

> SELECT DISTINCT MyTable1.value1,MyTable1.value2,MyTable2.status FROM
>   MyTable1,MyTable2 WHERE MyTable1.value1 = 103 AND MyTable2.value1 =
>   MyTable1.value1 AND MyTable2.value2 = MyTable1.value2

Anyway, I would like this result.

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| VALUE1 | VALUE2 | STATUS  |
+--------+--------+---------+
| 103    | 202    |         |
| 103    | 203    | WOW     |
| 103    | 205    |         |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't use implicit/comma join syntax. Always use explicit JOIN syntax. Then your problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Using a left join (as we want all records from T1 but only those that match in T2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.value1,T1.value2,T2.status 
FROM MyTable1 T1
LEFT JOIN MyTable2 T2
  on T2.value2 = T1.value2
 AND T2.value1 = T1.value1 
WHERE T1.value1 = 103
```

or using group by in case you need aggregation on value3

```
SELECT T1.value1,T1.value2,T2.status 
FROM MyTable1 T1
LEFT JOIN MyTable2 T2
  on T2.value2 = T1.value2
 AND T2.value1 = T1.value1 
WHERE T1.value1 = 103 
GROUP BY T1.value1,T1.value2,T2.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tb1.value1,
    tb1.value2, 
    tb2.status
FROM 
    table1 tb1 
LEFT JOIN
   table2 tb2 on tb1.value1 = tb2.value1
   and tb1.value2 = tb2.value2
WHERE 
  tb1.value1 = 103
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
  mt1.value1, 
  mt1.value2, 
  mt2.status
from mytable1 mt1, mytable2 mt2 
where mt1.value1 = mt2.value1 and mt1.value1 = 103
```

Comment: Likewise, don't use comma-join syntax.